# How to clone function with generic type

Tags: typescript

It has to be a simple way to do this:

```
const gfn = <T>(a: T) => a

// Doesn't work
const cloned = gfn<number>
```

How to get a cloned function with the generic already set?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like there is a simple way of just assigning the type parameter.

Two options would be:

```
const cloned: (a: number) => number = gfn; // this does not clone anything
const cloned2 = (a: number) => gfn(a); // actually a new function
```

Comment: Quick note: the first `cloned` can also be implemented via a generic if the type interface of `gfn` is extracted as this: `interface MyFn<T> { (a: T) : T }` then, it would be easier to do stuff like `const foo: MyFn<number> = gfn` or `const bar: MyFn<string> = gfn` for example and re-use the interface without having to write it every time. However, if you only need it once, no need for the extra interface.